# Analyzer + Code Fix not generating option

Tags: c#, roslyn, vsix, codefixprovider

I have an analyzer & Code fix that I want to make into a nuget package.

When I run this analyzer using the .VSIX project, the Analyzer highlights the correct option but the code fix does not show up when I look at the options (also occurs if I create a nuget package and install it).

When I expand the lightbulb options (codefix menu?) in the target project, the debug output in the VSIX prints "given range is not current".  [Looking at this roslyn code](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/EditorFeatures/Core.Wpf/Suggestions/SuggestedActionsSource.cs) suggests that the codefix is missing a document.

How can a document be missing from the context object that's passed to the codefix (or is something else happening here)?
And more importantly, how do I fix this?

Notes:
The analyzer and codefix run and work in VS 2019 preview, but don't work in VS 2019.
The analyzer and codefixprovider both have packagereferences in their .csproj files.